# How can I get a cell to return the most common value of 3 other cells that are all text based values, not numerical?

Tags: google-sheets

Cells A2, B2, & C2 all show answers to a specific question. I need E2 to produce the most common value from the results in A2:C2.

Eg. A2 contains "Orange," B2 contains "Purple," & C2 contains "Purple." So, the most common value is Purple. How do I get E2 to display "Purple?"

I have used MODE for this sort of thing in the past, but that only works for numerical values. Now I'm looking at text values and don't know how to find the most common value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may test this for **three** columns:*

```js
=let(Σ,A2:C2, +filter(Σ,countif(Σ,Σ)>1))
```

Comment: I've never seen the =let function before and I don't know what those symbols mean... But it worked! Thank you! Is to choose what it returns when there's no majority? Right now it just gives an error if there's empty spaces in the columns it's comparing or if there's no majority.

Comment: Instead of using `A2:C2` part 3 times within the formula, *let()* enables us to assign an identifier (I used *Σ* but you could use something else) to it and then we can keep using the identifier in place of the range A2:C2 as we write down the whole formula.

Comment: Right now the formula is strictly written to deal 3 cells and has a clear majority (replicating *mode*)

Comment: Ah-ha. I was having flashbacks to high school calculus but that makes sense. It could be any symbol. You've been very helpful. Thank you so much!